# get cterm color value

Tags: neovim, colorscheme

Currently all my colors are defined through Xresources and being set in vim through `ctermfg=2` for example. Lately there have been many improvements that rely on termguicolors being enabled (pumblend for example) that I can't use since I set my colors through cterm. Is there either a way to query the value of what `ctermfg=2` would be set to so I can assign it to guifg and then use termguicolors. This way my colors can still be defined through Xresources and I'd be able to use all the termguicolors dependent features as well.

Thanks!

EDIT for clarity: by setting ctermfg=2, what is the RGB value of color "2" and how can that be queried?

Comment: I should have clarified. What is the RGB value of color "2" in this case and how do I query that?

Comment: Just a SWAG but it depends on how you've configured vim (e.g. value of TERM envvar, settings like `t_AF`, `t_AB`). Color 2 could come from X resource `XTerm*color2`. (Recommended color, per `:h xfree-xterm`, would be green #008000) or it could come from whatever your terminal shows using `<ESC>[38;5;Nm` where N=2 ... e.g. `echo -e "\e[38;5;2m HELLO \e[m"`. Have you read the section starting with `:h xterm-color`?

Comment: I'm setting the colors through Xresources currently like this `*.color0:       #161b1d`. Your shell script worked to print out the text in green but I'm not clear on how to use this within vim. for instance `a = <color val of 2> | exe "hi Normal guifg=" . a`.

Comment: Honestly all I want to do is be able to use colors set through Xresources and have termguicolors enabled as well to make use of things like pumblend and whatnot. The main way I thought to do this was to query these values and then set them after `termguicolors` was set so they'd still be available. Maybe there's an easier way.

Comment: If you were using standard 256 colors in term I see the path. Because the colors are customized via Xresources I don't know if there's an easy way. (Not a regular user of X or xterm.) Where do you read those RGB values (e.g. `#161b1d` for `color0`). A config file? Worse comes to worst you could do a bit of scripting in Vim to read them and create a lookup from N to #xxxxxx. (BTW I deleted most of my earlier comments since neovim is a big different/simpler than vim...though that doesn't really help with the custom color scenario.)

Comment: I'm using 24 bit colors and they're being set in the the Xresources database. Currently setting `*color0: #161b1d` works for `hi Normal ctermbg=0`. That works as expected. It can be queried with `xrdb -query` but I'd prefer to avoid that if at all possible. I was expecting there to be some way to check the value of it within vim since presumably it has to get loaded and stored somewhere for `ctermbg=0` to work and then I could just query wherever it's being set.

Comment: Did you try other colors? The default ANSI 0 is black. RGB #161b1d is near black. They're likely indistinguishable from one another on many terminals+monitors. Just want to make sure we're not talking coincidence here...

Comment: I have verified that this is not coincidence.

Comment: Ok. Lemme think about it some more based on latest input. Maybe someone who has more immediate experience with this tech will come along in the meantime. :)